# how to run mysql query using foreach loop?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".stream").click(function(){
            stream = $('.stream:checked').map(function() {
                return this.value;
            }).get().join(', ');
              console.log(stream);
              alert(stream);
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"stream": stream},
                url:"stream.php",
                success:function(data){
                    $("#popular-colleges").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="stream" id="engineering" class="stream" value='engineering'>Engineering  
<input type="checkbox" name="stream" id="law" class="stream" value='law'>LAW<br/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="stream" id="medical" class="stream" value='medical'>Medical<br/>  
<input type="checkbox" name="stream" id="management" class="stream" value='management'>Management
```

stream.php

```
<?php 
    $streams = explode(",", $_POST['stream']);
    foreach ($streams as $stream) 
    {
        if($stream == 'engineering')
        {   
            $courses = "courses like '%,BTech,%' or courses like '%,MTech,%' or courses like '%,BCA,%'";
        }
        else if($stream == 'law') 
        {
            $courses = "courses like '%,LLB,%' or courses like '%,LLM,%' or courses like '%,BALLB,%'";     
        }
        else if($stream == 'medical') 
        {
            $courses = "courses like '%,MBBS,%' or courses like '%,MD,%' or courses like '%,BHMS,%'";        
        }
        else if($stream == 'management') 
        {
            $courses = "courses like '%,MBA,%' or courses like '%,BBA,%' or courses like '%,PGDM,%'";       
        }
    }
    echo "select * from all_colleges where ($courses) and city = '$city' order by priority desc ";   
?>
```

Here I have four checkbox with class stream and I am passing stream value to stream.php like engineering,law,medical when check multiple checkbox. Now I want that when I click on engineering checkbox it will run engineering query then law query similarly medical and management. I want multiple query on click on multiple checkbox. please help me.

Thank You

Comment: you didn't treat your checkboxes as arrays `[]`.

Comment: I am using map function @Fred-ii-

Comment: alrighty then ;-)

Comment: I'm curious though; why aren't you using radios instead? Checkboxes as an array suggests that you want to use a combination of. @kevin is that also what you wish to do, use a combo?

Comment: It's unlikely that `explode` will also `trim()` your entries.  You're passing in your data as "a, b" not "a,b" so the second entry will be " b" not "b".  Change `.join(', ')` to `.join(',')`

Comment: @kevin look at your console and check for errors on the query. I'd give you a link for it but I don't know which api you're using to connect with. You'll need to update your question about that, since it could be relevant and more code for the query.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes I know that, which is why I asked for clarification from the OP.

Comment: You'd also need to change `select * from all_colleges where ($courses) ` and ensure when you build $courses you and an and/or between each clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
// In javascript code replace 'get().join(', ');' with 'get().join(',');'

stream.php

$streams = explode(",", $_POST['stream']);
$city = 'indore';
$sql = [];
if (in_array('engineering', $streams)) {
    $sql[] = "courses like '%,BTech,%' or courses like '%,MTech,%' or courses like '%,BCA,%'";
}
if (in_array('law', $streams)) {
    $sql[] = "courses like '%,LLB,%' or courses like '%,LLM,%' or courses like '%,BALLB,%'";
}
if (in_array('medical', $streams)) {
    $sql[] = "courses like '%,MBBS,%' or courses like '%,MD,%' or courses like '%,BHMS,%'";
}
if (in_array('management', $streams)) {
    $sql[] = "courses like '%,MBA,%' or courses like '%,BBA,%' or courses like '%,PGDM,%'";
}

$query = "select * from all_colleges";

if (!empty($sql)) {
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' or ', $sql) . ' and city = '.$city.' order by priority desc ';
}

echo $query;
```